# pull request denied for openjdk

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
ENV APP_HOME=/root/dev/beverage
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . $APP_HOME
WORKDIR /app
RUN curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip -o gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
RUN unzip gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
ENV GRADLE_HOME=/app/gradle-6.5.1
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN gradle build



FROM opejdk:11.0.7-jre
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /root/dev/beverage/build/libs/bev-all.jar .
CMD ["java", "-jar", "bev-all.jar"]
```

When I try the following command:
`docker build -t beverage .`

I get the following:

```
Step 13/16 : FROM opejdk:11.0.7-jre
pull access denied for opejdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: 
requested access to the resource is denied
```

I tried many online tricks but nothing passes it. I am not sure what to do anymore.

Comment: `opejdk` needs an `n` in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm affraid you have a typo.
You've written `FROM opejdk:11.0.7-jre` instead of `FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jre`: ope**n**jdk